# How to return a 'list' object in Generics

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm a beginner with DRF. I want to return a sorted queryset so I do it and have some problems with returning a object list.
Here is my code:

```
class ProductListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        sort = [1,2,3,4]
        P = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(sort,P))]
        return P
```

And i got and error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Is there any way to return a list or solve this prolem?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`get_queryset` expects you to return a django queryset.  eg, something operating on the ORM via `Product.objects...`

You're returning a list, not a queryset, and there's no models inside said list

If you want to return a sorted queryset,

```
return self.queryset.order_by(<field>)
```

Your default position, when doing anything with the orm, queryset, etc, should be to have the database do it.  It will be much more performant than doing it in python.

Comment: Because I want to  sort a queryset based on values from another list so I can not use  order_by :(((((